# how to export a list of data to csv file in rest api

Tags: spring-boot, supercsv

I am exporting a list of user records to csv file in my sprig boot REST application. I am using supercsv maven dependency for this. My entity class for User & Address is like below.

## User

```
     Class User{

private String userId;
private String name;
private int age;
private double salary;
private List<Address> addresses;
}
```

## Address

```
 class Address{

private String id;
private String city;
private String street;
private String country;

}

enter code here
```

And my main controller class is like below.

```
@GetMapping("/exportCsv")
public ResponseEntity<?> exportCsv(HttpServletResponse response) {



    try {
    List<User> userList = getUserList();

    String csvFileName = "users.csv";

    response.setContentType("text/csv");

    // creates mock data
    String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
    String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"",
            csvFileName);
    response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);


    // write to csv file //

    ICsvBeanWriter csvWriter = new CsvBeanWriter(response.getWriter(),
            CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);

    String[]  user_headings = { "Name", "Age", "Salary" };

    String[] pojoclassPropertyName = { "name", "age", "salary"
            };

    csvWriter.writeHeader(account_headings);

    if(null!=userList && !userList.isEmpty()){
        for (User user : userList) {
            csvWriter.write(user, pojoclassPropertyName);
          }
        }
    csvWriter.close();

    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    return new ResponseEntity<>("successfully export to csv ",HttpStatus.OK);
```

with this data i can able to export the user name age salary data to csv file. but how could I pass the header for address in user_headings array and corresponding pojoclassPropertyName array mentioned above so that i can able to export all user and user address data to my csv file. kindly suggest me with any working example.

Comment: your user class definition is not fully included...

Comment: sorry about that, I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

As you added other properties (name, age, salary) of User class in the string array pojoclassPropertyName, you have to add the addresses property.

So the declaration should be like below:

String[] pojoclassPropertyName = { "name", "age", "salary", "addresses"};

Then you have to override **toString()** method in the **Address** class to return the data of the class address. This can be something like below:

```
class Address{

private String id;
private String city;
private String street;
private String country;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public String getStreet() {
    return street;
}

public void setStreet(String street) {
    this.street = street;
}

public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return getId() + " " + getStreet() + " " + getCity() + " " + getCountry();
}
```

}

This will write the addresses in csv file as you return in **toString()** method and if there is more than one address then it will be written with comma separated.

Comment: highlight the commands such as toString() and class names